# Can Media Type's suffix and subtype be used interchangeably?

Tags: http, content-type, specifications, media-type

Although it isn't stated directly in [IETF RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-4.3), after reading the text (and consulting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)) one can conclude that the general schema of a Media Type is as following:

```
type name / [ tree. ] subtype name [ +suffix ] [ ; parameters ]
```

Both Content Type and Accept HTTP Headers use Internet Media Types (as stated in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html)).

RFC 6838 also states the following about "+suffixes":

> "+suffix" constructs for as-yet unregistered structured syntaxes
> SHOULD NOT be used, given the possibility of conflicts with future
> suffix definitions.

[RFC 6839](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6839) defines the following registered suffixes:

```
"+json", "+ber", "+der", "+fastinfoset", "+wbxml" and "+zip"
```

---

Now, take the following data:

```
{
  "title": "<h1>Some formatted title</h1>",
  "body": "here's a <b>long</b> formatted text with <i>stuff</i>"
}
```

.

- Is `text/html+json` a good media type for this?
- What if, instead of JSON, I use YAML? (`text/html+yaml` violates RFC 6839 since it's not registered)
- And what if I want to build a parser that decodes data based on Content Type? Should I look for "subtype" or "suffix" for the appropriate "encoding"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. RFC 2616 is obsolete. Please look at RFC 7231.
2. I wouldn't use `html+json` for something that is a mix of HTML and JSON; you'd really need to translate all markup to JSON (at which point you'd realize that JSON doesn't work well for markup languages).
3. But yes, you could use `something+json`, as long as you register.
4. `+yaml` doesn't violate RFC 6839; but you would need to register it.
5. Generic software can use the suffix to select a parser. XMLHTTPRequest's support for `+xml` is an example.